# bind function to body from polymer element not working

Tags: jquery, html, function, polymer, bind

Im trying to make something similar to `paper-drawer-panel` but without main section as in original component. My custom drawer works fine, I just want to add few features for complete functionality. Toggle function works, but after opening drawer I want to add click and scroll handler to body, so if menu button not pressed again or not clicked element inside drawer it can be closed with click or scroll handler on body. Started from click handler but when added it to open function i get reference error that my function is not defined. I not sure where my code is wrong, because `openDrawer`/`closeDrawer` functions work, so I don't understand why `clickOnBody` function not working.

```html
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="mdl-drawer-panel">
 <template>

  <div id="mdlDrawer">
   <content id="mdlDrawerContent" select="[mdlDrawer]"></content>
  </div>
 </template>

  <script>
    (function(){
      var drawerElement = $('mdl-drawer-panel');
      var bodyElement = $('body');
      var isClosed = 'true';
      Polymer({
        is: 'mdl-drawer-panel',
        properties: {

        },

        togglePanel: function() {
          if (isClosed) {
            this.openDrawer();
          } else {
            this.closeDrawer();
          }
          isClosed = !isClosed;
        },

        openDrawer: function() {
          drawerElement.removeClass('transClose');
          drawerElement.addClass('transOpen');
          bodyElement.bind('click', clickOnBody); // Add click listener
          console.log('is drawer opened ? ( ' +isClosed+ ' )');
        },

        closeDrawer: function() {
          drawerElement.removeClass('transOpen');
          drawerElement.addClass('transClose');
          bodyElement.unbind('click', clickOnBody); // Remove click listener
          console.log('is drawer opened ? ( ' +isClosed+ ' )');
        },

        clickOnBody: function(){
          bodyElement.togglePanel();
          console.log('clicked');
        }
      });
    }());
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**Update!**
when add '*this*' to bodyElement.bind('click', this.clickOnBody); it throws another error - togglePanel() is not a function. But why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some weird things going on in your code :)

1. Why the selectors in the top of your script? Is that jQuery by the way?
2. I think you mean to declare isClosed as [property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties).
3. `togglePanel` is not a function of `<body>`. That's why you're getting the error
4. You should use [DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api) to manipulate nodes inside Polymer

You should definitely work on separation of concerns. I've made some changes to your code. See snippet below.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'mdl-drawer-panel',
  properties: {
    isClosed: {
      value: true
    }
  },

  togglePanel: function() {
    if (this.isClosed) {
      this.openDrawer();
    } else {
      this.closeDrawer();
    }
    this.isClosed = !this.isClosed;
  },

  openDrawer: function() {
    Polymer.dom(this).classList.remove('transClose');
    Polymer.dom(this).classList.add('transOpen');
    
    console.log('is drawer opened ? ( ' +this.isClosed+ ' )');
  },

  closeDrawer: function() {
    Polymer.dom(this).classList.remove('transOpen');
    Polymer.dom(this).classList.add('transClose');
    
    console.log('is drawer opened ? ( ' +this.isClosed+ ' )');
  }  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body style="height: 200px">
  <mdl-drawer-panel></mdl-drawer-panel>
  
  <dom-module id="mdl-drawer-panel">
      <template>
          <div id="mdlDrawer">
              <content id="mdlDrawerContent" select="[mdlDrawer]"></content>
          </div>
      </template>
  </dom-module>
  
  <script>
    var bodyElement = document.querySelector('body');
    var drawerElement = document.querySelector('mdl-drawer-panel');
    
    bodyElement.addEventListener('click', clickOnBody);
    
    function clickOnBody(){
      drawerElement.togglePanel();
      console.log('clicked');
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

See that I moved some code to script in HTML body. Also, I'd encourage you to use native JS as much as possible.

Comment: Tomasz Pluskiewicz yes that was jquery and function to body binds after drawer is opened and unbinds after closing it

Comment: Tomasz Pluskiewicz, tested your solution it worksgreat exception is when adding element to body also need to add property to it. (is-closed="true") if not then to open drawer after page loads need to press button twice.